# Why does this parameterized sql query not return results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am taking over a VB project and with my limited VB skills I cannot get the following to parameterized query to return results:

```
Dim strSQLUser As String = "Select Name, CompanyID from Users where UserName = @UserName"
dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQLUser, dbConn)
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User)
dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
```

However this is the original code that does work:

```
Dim strSQLUser As String = "Select Name, CompanyID from Users where UserName ='" & User & "'"
dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQLUser, dbConn)
dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
```

As you can see the original code was vulnerable to sql injection and needs to be fixed.

Extra - Here is the line that does the reading:

```
While dr.Read
  DbUser = dr.GetValue(0).ToString
  DbCompany = dr.GetValue(1).ToString
End While
```

Comment: I suppose that the variable User is a string right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using parameters you do not specify the quotes around parameters `'`. All the parameters are automatically converted to their respective column types such as date, nvarchar etc. So no more quotes.

```
Dim strSQLUser As String = "Select Name, CompanyID from Users where UserName =@UserName"
```

Comment: I thought so just before I posted the question, and tried it out, without any results.

Comment: I have added the updated version of the question since the problem was still not resolved, even though you did point out a mistake.

Comment: It seems that for some strange reason you must have no spaces between `=@` symbol

Comment: It does not matter whether you use space or not be it like " =@", "=@" or " = @" all should work

Comment: As a precaution you should not use keywords like `User` as variables, control names, literals

Comment: That space between = and @ actually prevented the query from returning results. Don't know why. Like I mentioned I took this project over and I still need to fix basic problems like these.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim strSQLUser As String = "Select Name, CompanyID from Users where UserName =@UserName"
dbCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQLUser, dbConn)
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Text)
dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
```

Also the better approach is provide the value as:

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Text
```

Assuming User to be the varchar ie., text type.

Comment: Thanks for answer, seems like I had a mistake with `=@` having a space, since haraman did give the correct answer first I will mark his as correct.

Comment: @Nightwolf:- Ok no problem, also as a reminder do check the correct way of providing parameters which I have added in my answer. Yours way is not recommended. And yes the space between = and @ doesnt matter.

Comment: I was tried `SqlDbType.VarChar` but did not know you don't have to give the length and thought this could be a reason for query failure. I will be using your suggestion.

Comment: That space between = and @ actually prevented the query from returning results. Don't know why.

Comment: @Nightwolf:- That sounds really strange to me.